# Python order dataset weather

Tags: python, dataset, ranking

I have a dataset history of temperature/weather by city like this:

```
{"city": "Barcelona", "date": "2016-10-16", "temperature": "13", "weather": "cloudy"}
{"city": "Berlin", "date": "2016-10-16", "temperature": "-1", "weather": "sunny"}
{"city": "Pekin", "date": "2016-10-16", "temperature": "19", "weather": "cloudy"}
{"city": "Paris", "date": "2016-10-16", "temperature": "-8", "weather": "sunny"}
```

And I would like to create a top 5, order by best average temperature.In this result I would like to know the number of day by weather type(sunny cloudy rainy)

Example:

```
Rank - City -      Average Temperature - Cloudy days - Sunny days - Rainy Days
1 -    Barcelona -           20 -           93 -        298 -       29
```

How can doing this in Python?

Thanks

Matt

Comment: You have a file of JSON line data?

Comment: Also, the best way would probably be pandas.

Comment: Yes, each line are in Json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

- first [`read_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) for `DataFrame` from `json`
- get top 5 cities by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregate `mean` and [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html)
- filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)
- aggregate by `count`s, reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html)
- [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by `index` of `s` for correct ordering
- add new columns by  [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html)
- last add rank with `range`

---

```
import pandas as pd

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('a.json', lines=True)
print (df)
        city       date  temperature weather
0  Barcelona 2016-10-16           13  cloudy
1     Berlin 2016-10-16           -1   sunny
2      Pekin 2016-10-16           19  cloudy
3      Paris 2016-10-16           -8   sunny

s = df.groupby(['city'])['temperature'].mean().nlargest(5)
print (s)
city
Pekin        19
Barcelona    13
Berlin       -1
Paris        -8
Name: temperature, dtype: int64
```

---

```
df2 = (df[df['city'].isin(s.index)]
               .groupby(['city', 'weather'])['temperature']
               .size()
               .unstack(fill_value=0)
               .add_suffix(' days')
               .reindex(s.index)
               .reset_index()
               .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

df2.insert(1, 'temp avg', df2['city'].map(s))
df2.insert(0, 'rank', range(1, len(df2) + 1))
print (df2)
   rank       city  temp avg  cloudy days  sunny days
0     1      Pekin        19            1           0
1     2  Barcelona        13            1           0
2     3     Berlin        -1            0           1
3     4      Paris        -8            0           1
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael but the "print(df2)" does not return in the good order. I've try with more data(see my post, I've added 2 rows). The firt print is well ordered but not the second.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I add `reindex` for correct ordering.

Comment: It's perfect! Thanks a lot.